# Filter HTTP requests using JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, filter, python-requests

I'm trying to disable/suspend Facebook Pixel tracker on a WordPress-based website's page by using JavaScript. After succeeding it, it was keeping running. So, I decided to prevent requests from this site's pages to be done to a specific URL (e.g.: https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js). I used the Ajax Prefilter options but I failed. If someone could help me or give me other effeective ideas, it could be very nice.

If you need further information I could have forgotten, let me know.

Thanks in advance!

NB: if you want to look a the traker's code, here's the URL :https://www.stimium.com.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not an example of a good question. For a good question, you must provide a detailed description or the problem, a detailed description of the desired output, your current attempts so far in order to eliminate potential repeated attempts. See here: [How to ask a Good Question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can not filter arbitrary requests made by a website or any scripts embedded to it using JavaScript running inside the page itself … _“I used the Ajax Prefilter options”_ - that would only make sense if the Facebook pixel script used the AJAX implementation of _your_ library to begin with … how likely is that?

Comment: Thank you for responding. I see for "Ajax Prefilter" and forget about it. The idea would be to enable or disable this FB Pixel tracker programmatically by using JavaScript as would do tarteaucitronjs script (https://github.com/AmauriC/tarteaucitron.js/) but this script doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get any response so I think it could be great to explain how I could handle this.

I repeat, my need was to disable or enable Google Analytics, Facebook Pixel and other trackers folowwing the visitor's choice. Actually, I'm in a need of puting an overlay to get users' consent to use third-party cookies (due to European GDPR law). So, here's an example of code preventing the FB Pixel tracker to which I gave "fbpix" id attribute :

```
 document.addEventListener("readystatechange", function(){document.getElementById("fbpix").removeAttribute("type"); document.getElementById("fbpix").setAttribute("type", "text/javascript"); });
```

Put this between  tags. I tested it with bifferent browsers and it could block the tracker's execution at page's loading and I didn't get any FB Pixel cookie.

There might still be better solutions but it's all I found out.